# Tailwind Css Intelisense not workin in VSCODE while working on Django-HTML page

Tags: django, tailwind-css, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I installed Tailwind css intelisense plugin in Vscode.

But my intelisense is not working in Vscode.

I put below code in Vscode settings.json file as well --

```
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
        "html": "html",
        "django-html": "html",
        "javascript": "javascript",
        "css": "css"
    },
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    },
    "css.validate": false,
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.css": "tailwindcss"
    }
```

Still my intelisense not working in vscode.

Comment: Have you found a solution? intelisense for tailwind worked for me like 3 months ago but now it doesn't and I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why put for me Tailwind CSS IntelliSense was working in my Django project put stopped for no reason probably after a vs code or plugin update.

I assume because I'm using django tailwind the deep nested tailwind.config.js doesn't trigger the intellisense plugin. **A workaround**, that worked for me was adding an additional but empty `tailwind.config.js` file at the top level of the project.